# static global object

Tags: java, field, global

I've got class with one static method

> makeConnection

The method returns Connection object for further JDBC operations. Is there a possibility, to create a global Connection field, with result of this method "return" ? I would like to use this field wherever I need.

```
public class Connection 
{
    public static Connection makeConnection() throws IOException, SQLException
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            Properties props = new Properties();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("dataBase.properties");
            props.load(in);
            in.close();

            String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
            if(drivers != null) System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
            String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
            String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");

            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,password);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
        return null;
    }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }  
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            return null;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like `class Foo { static Connection conn = bar(); static Connection bar() { ... } }`?

Comment: If by global you mean static to your class, then yes. I have to point out that this is a really bad design though, the JDBC Connection object is not built to be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the connection factory is better than a connection. 
However, static variable is not a good idea for the lifecycle control of connections.

A good connection pool will take care many problem for you, such as the concurrent accessing, timed out detecting, recycle the alive connections, purging dead connections automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
class Foo {

    public static Connection conn = bar();

    private static Connection bar() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: That would be fine, but compiler returns error because of unreproted Exceptions in line with conn declaration. Am i missing something, or this is some king of dead circle?

Comment: This will work if you have `bar()` catch the exception and either return `null` or throw a runtime exception to stop the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* the way to handle connections ... but it might give you an idea how to resolve similar kinds of problems:

```
public class Wombat
{
    public static Wombat getWombat () 
    {
      if (theWombat == null)
        theWombat = new Wombat ();
      return theWombat;
    }

    private static Wombat theWombat= null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a static variable in a static initializer block:

```
class Foo {
   public static Connection conn;

   static {
      try {
         conn = makeConnection();
      } catch(...) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```